# Euclidean geometry (triangles) - homework

Tags: geometry

I am struggling with a geometry question that our noble professor gave to us. He wants us to prove that given an acute triangle ABC, if we construct an equilateral triangle that shares a side CA with the acute triangle (and has an orientation into the acute triangle) then the vertex of the equilateral triangle not on CA will be contained in the angle ABC.

I hope you can help me with this difficult problem. Good day to all, enjoy your time working on my problem, instead of working on your problems.

My work on the problem so far: I see that if our acute triangle is in fact equilateral the two triangles will coincide. Other than that, I havent really come up with anything useful.

(Please dont give me solutions involving analytic geometry. Our government scientist hasnt invented algebra yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a square $ACXY$, with $A$ at the origin and $C$ at the x-axis. Inscribe equilateral triangle $ACD$. Also, draw a semicircle $AEC$ with $AC$ the diameter and $E$ inside the square Pick any point $B$ lower than $D$, inside the square, and outside the semicircle. Triangle $ABC$ is a counterexample to your professor's claim.